# Dual booting Windows and Linux with NVMe M.2 and another SSD

Tags: dual-boot, ssd

I currently have a 970 Evo Plus 1TB M.2 NVMe with Windows and a old 120 GB PNY SSD with Windows on it as well. I was thinking about playing around with Linux distros on my old SSD so I still have my Windows for main functionality. I wanted to double check what I needed to do.

I'm thinking that...

1. I just wipe my old SSD
2. Put the Linux ISO on a bootable drive
3. Detach my M.2 temporarily to install Linux
4. Install Linux on my SSD

After that, if I prioritize Linux as my boot drive, it should let me have the option to boot between Windows or Linux when I start up right? Not sure if I'm missing any steps and I don't want to mess up my Windows drive...

Comment: You haven't mentioned what OS/release you are talking about, only a generic Linux, please provide details.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know it would be a different process for distros. I'm looking at the latest versions for Ubuntu and Debian. Is there anything else I should include?

Comment: Depending on which Ubuntu ISO you download, you can choose a *di* (*debian installer*), `ubiquity`, `subiquity` or `calamares` installer which can be slightly different (mainly in how you do things). Debian is off-topic here so you won't get answers for that or other distros (that may differ).  Ubuntu should be installed in the same mode (UEFI/secure-UEFI/legacy..) as windows (to dual boot), and personally I'd not remove the windows drive, but adjust for your release & ISO/installer selected.

Comment: Be sure to install in UEFI boot mode. You may not have to physically disconnect M.2 drive, but just in UEFI settings set to "disabled". You probably need to both Update UEFI & SSD firmware for both drives. And still have to have Windows fast boot off, if you then want to add it to grub menu for dual booting.